# Decreasing sequence of special form

Tags: commutative-algebra, real-analysis

Is there a (strictly) decreasing sequence $(a_n + b_n \sqrt{2})_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ of positive reals, where $a_n,b_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: @M.G. thank you .

Comment: $(\sqrt{2}-1)^n$